# Filter arrays with bitmask or other array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was wondering if there was an Array method in Ruby that allows to filter an array based on another array or a bitmask.

Here is an example and a quick implementation for illustration purposes:

```
class Array
  def filter(f)
    res = []
    if f.is_a? Integer
      (0...self.size).each do |i|
        res << self[i] unless f[i].nil? || 2**i & f == 0
      end
    else
      (0...self.size).each do |i|
        res << self[i] unless f[i].nil? || f[i] == 0
      end
    end
    return res
  end
end
```

Example:

```
%w(a b c).filter([1, 0, 1]) ==> ['a', 'c']
%w(a b c).filter(4) ==> ['c']
%w(a b c).filter([1]) ==> ['a']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ruby 1.9 `Fixnum#[]` gives you bit values at a particular position, so it will work for both integers and arrays.  I'm thinking something like this:

```
class Array
    def filter f
        select.with_index { |e,i| f[i] == 1 }
    end
end

%w(a b c).filter([1, 0, 1]) #=> ['a', 'c']
%w(a b c).filter(4) #=> ['c']
%w(a b c).filter(5) #=> ['a', c']
%w(a b c).filter([1]) #=> ['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
    def filter(f)
        f = f.to_s(2).split("").map(&:to_i) unless Array === f
        reverse.reject.with_index{|_, i| f[-i].to_i.zero?}
    end
end
```

Comment: I think the `2**i != f` part will run into problems when you try a mask with more than one value, for example `%w(a b c).filter(5)`.  The `f[i].zero?` will also fail on the last example where there are less values in the filter array than the original one, since it will try to call `#zero?` on NilClass.